# draw a line between two divs in a responsive theme?

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

For a responsive layout, I'm drawing lines between two divs with canvas, but the problem I have is :
- how can i keep the lines stay respectively in position with the center of the divs when resizing the window  ?

I added a resize listener, and recreate the x / y points every time the user resize the window, but I'm stuck to find the perfect math formula to calculate this right.

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
```

Please see the example here : http://jsfiddle.net/FZNMk/1/ 
You have to resize the window to make the line appears.
Thanks

Comment: The fiddle isn't really showing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to bind the onresize event to your body, once you catch the event you just need to resize the canvas using window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight.

The proper code would be something like this

```
<body onresize="resize_canvas()">
    <canvas id="canvas">Your browser doesn't support canvas</canvas>
</body>
```

I have not tried it but this is the basic idea of doing the things in right way

Comment: I'm doing that already, see the example, my problem is how to calculate the coordinates to find the center of the boxes when I resize? because the position.offset is relative to the window page and not to the container of my divs
And can the canvas be set width=100%  ?